# What is the difference between 201 status code and 204 status code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

[image]

what is the difference between 201 and 204

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#successful_responses

Comment: What don't you understand about the explanations you've provided?

Comment: @gunr2171 The provided information is not correct. e.g. 201 means `Created`

Comment: ok but these two are showing same description ,so i need to create a separate methods for these two, how can i write that separate method by using preferred return type.

Comment: (Correction) Where did you get this image from? What the "numbers" for HTTP status codes mean are mearly suggestions. You _can_ have a "404" mean "not found", or you can have it mean something entirely different. 201 from what you've posted doesn't happen to agree with MDN, and that's fine, but who's definition are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In practice, there isn't a lot of difference between a 200 with no content, a 201 and a 204: they all generically mean that the request succeeded:

- a 200 response is the generic OK, and may or may not have a body
  attached;
- a 201 response is for when the request specifically creates
  something and does not have a response body; and
- a 204 response is for when the request succeeds but has no body to
  return.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201) 201 should return data. And the [RFC 9110: HTTP Semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#status.201) even mention that content is typically returned.

Comment: Hi @StianJørgensrud! Yes, will often return data, but not necasarily in the body. For example, it's common pattern for the 201 response to have a location header added, which contains the URI for the new resource that was created.

Answer (score 1):

Both `201` and `201` represent a successful request, For a more detailed explanation you can refer to the following documentation

**201 Created**

> The request has been fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new
> resources being created. The primary resource created by the request
> is identified by either a Location header field in the response or, if
> no Location field is received, by the effective request URI.

**204 No Content**

> The server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no
> additional content to send in the response payload body.

Answer (score 0):

200: OK *Return an entity describing or containing the result of the action* -
when an object is created and returned (typically JSON for REST endpoint).

If all is OK, but there is no data to return the code is 204 No Content.

201: CREATED. *The request has been fulfilled and resulted in a new resource being created.* - when an object is created but only its reference is returned (such as an ID or a link)